# How do i write server-side-only custom directives with nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm writing a permission directive which should been executed only server-side.

I've tried add a `permission.js` file in the `plugins` directory and referenced this plugin in `nuxt.config.js`, but it turned out to be useful only on client-side.

I've also tried configure it in the `nuxt.config.js` like below:

```
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      directives: {
        permissions: () => {
          console.log(1234)
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

It worked on server-side, but turned out throwing errors like `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: permissions` on client-side

So how do I write a server-side-only directive which will not affect client-side code?